# org-capture crashing Emacs

Tags: org-mode, crash

Running org-capture crashes my Emacs (both 24.3 and 24.4 for Linux).

This [thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-10/msg00850.html) reports the problem is due to cdlatex not being installed.  But installing it does not solve the problem on my computer.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried explicitly uninstalling it? There may be some old byte-compiled files lying around that are messing things up.

Comment: Have you tried a bare-bones `capture-templates` setup in case something in your setting is causing the issue -- perhaps try just one simple entry in the `capture-templates` variable?  Try also just one `org-agenda-files` instead of many.  Reduce your setup to a bare minimum.

Comment: Please update with `M-x org-version`.  Also, use a minimal setup (start Emacs with `emacs -Q` and load only `org-mode` and `org-capture`) and report if you still have the crashing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a conflict with the auto-capitalize mode.

Comment: For the benefit of future readers, please specify what the conflict was and how to resolve it.  Then, if you've successfully answered your own question, please accept your own answer so that others will know the problem has been solved.

Comment: There is something like a 36 to 48 hour waiting period to accept one's own answer.